# Read json file inside a zip file without decompression remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms

I am trying to read a zip file remotly from a url this bit works fine if its from disk but I want to read it remotly without unzipping the file first is that possible or would it make the file inacessable to others?.

```
public void GetMSFSAddonDetails(string zipFileUrl) {
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFileUrl))
    {
       var sample = archive.GetEntry("manifest.json");
       if (sample != null)
       {
          using (var zipEntryStream = sample.Open())
       {
           // serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SampleClass));

          /// SampleClass deserialized =
            //  (SampleClass)serializer.Deserialize(zipEntryStream);
      
       }
      
}
```

**Edit 2**
I am getting the following error when i try to donwload a zip file from the url

This is using android forms with the mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" 
  package="com.companyname.msfsaddonshub.forms" android:installLocation="auto">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="28" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
 <application android:label="MSFSAddonsHub.Forms.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open (System.String archiveFileName,
> System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode mode) [0x00000] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/src/System/IO/Compression/ZipFile.cs:81
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead (System.String archiveFileName)
> [0x00000] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/src/System/IO/Compression/ZipFile.cs:39
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> MSFSAddonsHub.BL.MSFSBL.GetMSFSAddonDetails (System.String zipFileUrl)
> [0x00001] in
> D:\GitMaster\MSFSAddonsHub\MSFSAddonsHub.BL\MSFSAddonsHub.BL\MSFSBL.cs:17
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> MSFSAddonsHub.BL.MSFSBL.DownloadTestFile () [0x00001] in
> D:\GitMaster\MSFSAddonsHub\MSFSAddonsHub.BL\MSFSAddonsHub.BL\MSFSBL.cs:13
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> MSFSAddonsHub.Forms.Views.MainMenu..ctor () [0x0001a] in
> D:\GitMaster\MSFSAddonsHub\MSFSAddonsHub.Forms\MSFSAddonsHub.Forms\MSFSAddonsHub.Forms\Views\MainMenu.xaml.cs:20
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> (wrapper managed-to-native)
> System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object
> obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions)
> [0x00005] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/RuntimeMethodInfo.cs:936
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]    ---
> End of inner exception stack trace --- 01-03 08:10:43.333
> F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object
> obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions)
> [0x00018] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/RuntimeMethodInfo.cs:944
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic,
> System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00095] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:185
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly,
> System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Boolean skipCheckThis,
> System.Boolean fillCache) [0x00009] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:155
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean
> publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache,
> System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark&
> stackMark) [0x00027] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5770
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean
> nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00039] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:206
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at
> System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean
> nonPublic) [0x00000] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:190
> 01-03 08:10:43.333 F/addonshub.form( 6899): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   a

Comment: What do you mean by "without unzipping the file first"? Also, as per your code it seems like you're already attempting to read the stream of the file you're interested in, so what is your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the method `ZipFile.OpenRead(String)` does not handle URLs! It expects an `archiveFileName` and searches on the disk.

You would probably have to download the zip file and open it afterwards.

Comment: Microsoft documentation agrees https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.openread?view=net-5.0